# How to prevent keyboard shortcuts that activate Chrome extensions from resetting?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

I use Google Chrome's **Keyboard shortcuts** to activate extensions very often.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts in Google Chrome]

Regrettably, the keyboard shortcuts I set disappear every now and then. I often need to reconfigure the shortcuts.

I'm not sure if the reset happens because Chrome updates or if I added a new extension, or disabled one. Can anything be done to prevent the Keyboard shortcuts from resetting?